# C# Xamarin - Binding data to UICollectionViewCell using SetValueForKey

Tags: c#, ios, data-binding, xamarin, uicollectionview

I am having significant problems using Xamarin.iOS.

I come from a MVC5 web background and would often bind data to DOM elements (for example with JS `data-` attributes). I want to achieve a similar pattern in Xamarin.iOS.

From what I gather in Xamarin's documentation (which always seems to be based on obsolete versions of the framework) I need to bind data (but not display it) to a `UICollectionViewCell` using the KVC pattern.

Is the best method calling `SetValueForKey(NSObject object, NString key)` within my UpdateCell method (NOTE: I have changed the params to be generic):

```
 public class MyClassCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell 
 {
     [Outlet]
     UILabel NameLabel { get; set; }

     public BaseCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
     {
         this.NameLabel = new UILabel();
     }

     public virtual void UpdateCell(MyClass myClassObject)
     {
         // Display the "Name" within the UILabel outlet
         this.NameLabel.Text = myClassObject.Name;

         // This being my custom cell which inherits from UICollectionViewCell
         this.SetValueForKey(myClassObject, "BoundMyClassObject");

         // remainder omitted for brevity
     }
 }
```

And MyClass.cs (again, not it's real name but for illustration)

```
public class MyClass 
{
     [JsonProperty("Id")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("Name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     // more props omitted for brevity
}
```

Is the problem that the object I am trying to bind does not inherit from `NSObject` and therefore will not work with `SetValueForKey`.

I am hoping to bind the object to a cell, tap the cell, retrieve data bound to cell and finally make a REST call using the bound data.

The reason for this? Well I want the "Name" MyClass property to appear on the `UICollectionViewCell`'s label and the "Id" to be accessible for the REST call but not displayed to the user. Currently the label appears the TapGesture works but I am unable to retrieve the value for myClassObject.Id and thus cannot make a web call!

The `UITapGestureRecognizer` is wired up to the `UICollectionView` within  my `UICollectionViewController`- code not required for scope of question) and corrently fires an event but requires the value for key "BoundMyClassObject" or myClassObject.Id to POST as JSON...

Make sense?

Please help me out as there is very little information within Xamarin documentation and forums.

All the best,

John

***EDIT***

As [@AdamKemp](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5130/setvalueforkey) points out in the post here `SetValueForKey` is meant for `NSObject`s.

So I refactored the code in `MyClass.cs` as follows

[Register("MyClass)]
    public class My Class : NSObject
    {
        public MyClass() { }

```
    public MyClass(int ID)
    {
        this.Id = ID;
    }

    private int _Id = 0;
    [Export("Id")]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            WillChangeValue("Id");
            _Id = value;
            DidChangeValue("Id");
        }
    }

    // same for Name property
}
```

However when I call `SetValueForKey` within my `UpdateCell` method

```
 MyClass myClassObject = newMyClass(7); // int passed to constructor for illustration in my real code it's dynamic

    this.SetValueForKey(myClassObject, "MyClassObject");
```

I encounter the following error

```
Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSUnknownKeyException Reason: [<UICollectionViewCell 0x7e433a30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key MyClassObject.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

I added the following properties to my UICollectionViewCell class:

```
[Export("Id")]
NSNumber Id { get; set; }
[Export("Name")]
NSString Name { get; set; }
```

And also changes the arguments passed to `SetValueForKey`

```
this.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber(7), 
                    new NSString("Id"));
```

Then it will correctly allocate the value 7 to the property of this UICollectionViewCell. Note that your properties must ALL be decorated with `[Export]`.

In fact the `MyClass.cs` is no longer needed - if you place the properties within the custom UICollectionViewCell and call `SetValueForKey` to initialize them.

They can then be read out anywhere by using

```
NSNumber instanceID = (NSNumber)cell.ValueForKey(new NSString("Id"));
```

Then you can use the data retrieved from this call and pass to your data access layer as necessary.

As an aside, the `SetValueForKey` method expects an `NSObject` (or a child of this) as the first argument. Annoyingly `NSDate` can be a pain so I made an extension method for converting C# `DateTime` to `NSDate` for easy data binding:

```
public static NSDate DateTimeToNSDate(DateTime date)
{
    return NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate((date - (new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))).TotalSeconds);
}

public static DateTime NSDateToDateTime(NSDate date)
{
    return (new DateTime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(date.SecondsSinceReferenceDate);
}
```

Finally, see [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/databinding/) Xamarin tutorial for more information on data binding.

I hope this helps people in the future! (Hi future people - has the singularity occurred yet?)